# Publish multi module library to maven

Tags: android, maven, gradle, build.gradle

I have a small library that I publish to Gitlab Package Registery using the `maven-publish` Gradle plugin.

I decided to split it into 2 modules, one named `core` (published as `com.mycompany.core:core`) and the other `view` (published as `com.mycompany.core:view`). Since the `view` module rely on the `core` module, I added `implementation project(":core")` to its `build.gradle`

Now if I add my `com.mycompany.core:view:1.0` dependency to another project, I get the error

> Failed to resolve: Core:core:unspecified

Now if I replace `implementation project(":core")` by `implementation "com.mycompany.core:core:1.0"`, I can't even build my `view` module because of course this version of the `core` module is not yet published.

How can I solve this dependency problem?

EDIT: settings.gradle content

```
include ':core', ':view'
rootProject.name = "Core"
```

Comment: have you updated the setting.gradle ? you need to add `include ':core'`

Comment: @George Yes. I added my settings.gradle content to the post